# how to implement a stack using a generic dynamic array?

Tags: c, arrays, generics, dynamic, stack

I recently started developing a generic library to create a stack using generic dynamic arrays, I have some doubts about the use of the generic arrays. When creating the struct; should I somehow specify the type of array I am going to use?

In the various insert/delete operations how do I pass a value of type `void *` to my generic array?

```
  struct arraystack{
       int size;
       unsigned capacity;
       void *array;
  };
```

Comment: what is size and what is capacity?

Comment: size is the index of my array
while capacity indicates the amount of memory allocated

Comment: You have to decide what you're storing in your array — pointers to chunks of memory managed by the user, or copies of chunks of memory passed by the user. You also need to decide whether all chunks in an `arraystack` will be the same size or not, and which code needs to know about that size (and where it's stored). You can find some 'array of memory' code in my [SOQ](https://github.com/jleffler/soq) (Stack Overflow Questions) repository on GitHub as files `aomcopy.[ch]`, `aomptr.[ch]` and `aommngd.[ch]` in the [src/libsoq](https://github.com/jleffler/soq/tree/master/src/libsoq) sub-directory.